# How can I place two headings next to each other using CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-heading

```
<h5>Category</h5><h6>auto</h6>
```

places **Category** and **auto** on separate lines, like this:

### Category

#### auto

How can I place them both on the same line, like this?

### Category auto

Answer (score 29, accepted):

h(n) elements are 'block' elements, which means they will grow to take all available horizontal space. This also means they will push anything "right" of them down to the next line.

One easy way to accomplish this is to set their display to inline:

```
<style>
    h5, h6 {display:inline;}
</style>
```

Note that `inline-block` is **not** supported in all browsers.

You can also float block elements, but that can become a sticky issue as floating can be fairly complex. Stick with inline for cases like this.

Comment: Can you tell which browsers are not supporting the inline-block display mode?

Comment: @Gertjan IE only supports it for elements which are natively inline; FF2 does not support it at all.

Answer (score 7):

```
<h5 style="display:inline-block;">Category</h5>
<h6 style="display:inline-block;">auto</h6>
```

Comment: inline-block is not supported in all browsers.

Comment: This is possible, however using inline styles is not a recommended way of working. Your solution is not wrong, but I think it is better to show a much nicer way of working by using stylesheets or a style definition on top of the document.

Comment: for IE, 'inline-block' is restricted to <span> <strong> <em>

Comment: @ertjan: I agree. It was just a minimalistic version to communicate the idea.

Answer (score 4):

You must change the display mode of the elements. H tags are rendered as BLOCK elements by default. To override this behavior add the following style definitions to your website or CSS

```
h5,h6 { display: inline; }
```

You can also decide to let them "float" next to each other you can do that via:

```
h5,h6 { float: left; }
```

Please note that floating only works on block elements (so using both styles will perform no float because inline elements cannot float).